# How to have 2 pager in jqgrid one at top and one at bottom?

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid, pager

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#jqgProducts').jqGrid({
         url: '/Home/GridSampleData/', // url from which data should be requested
         datatype: 'json',             // type of data
         mtype: 'GET',                 // url access method type
         colNames: ['userid', 'username', 'email', 'contact', 'password'],
         colModel: [                   // columns model
             { name: 'userId', index: 'userId', align: 'left',
               editable: false },
             { name: 'username', index: 'username', align: 'left',
               editable: true, edittype: 'text',
               editoptions: { maxlength: 20 },
               editrules: { required: true} },
             { name: 'email', index: 'email', align: 'left', editable: true,
               edittype: 'text', editoptions: { maxlength: 50 },
               editrules: { required: true} },
             { name: 'contact', index: 'contact', align: 'left',
               editable: true, edittype: 'text',
               editoptions: { maxlength: 20 }, editrules: { required: true} },
             { name: 'password', index: 'password', align: 'left',
               editable: true, edittype: 'password',
               editoptions: { maxlength: 20 },
               editrules: { required: true} }
         ],
         pager: $('#jqgpProducts'), // pager for grid
         rowNum: 5,                 // number of rows per page
         sortname: 'userId',        // initial sorting column
         sortorder: 'asc',          // initial sorting direction
         viewrecords: true,         // we want to display total records count
         width: '600',              // grid width
         height: 'auto'             // grid height
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 21):

Include "toppager: true" to the list of jqGrid options. This do exactly what you want: "When enabled this option place a pager element at top of the grid below the caption (if available). If another pager is defined both can coexists and are refreshed in sync."

The full list of options you can find on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: @Allen: You welcome! If you want more customization of the pager my another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663 could be also interesting for you.

Comment: @Oleg - does that put it at the top center or the top left ??

Comment: @ooo: "toppager: true" creates the same pager as one see typically at the bottom.

Comment: @Oleg. I used toppager: true and cloneToTop: true, however my search, refresh and column-reordering/hiding buttons are not transferred to the toppager. Only the pagination buttons appear at the top. Do I have to explicitly add those buttons to the top pager?

Comment: @keithxm23: If you use `cloneToTop: true` all buttons added by `navGrid` will be added to two pager. I recommend you to read two old answers: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3557663/315935), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4402903/315935), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511348/315935) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854864/315935). If all the answers will don't help you to solve your problem you should describe your problem more exactly and you should post the corresponding code example which you use.

Answer (score 0):

This is 4 years late but I saw something like this, template option

```
 template: '<div>' +
             '<div class="jqgrid-pagination"></div>' +
             '<table></table>' +
             '<div class="jqgrid-pagination"></div>' +               
           '</div>',
```