# toolbar in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I would like to create a toolbar in jqGrid with only the buttons that usually are on the pager.

At the moment I have the following definition

```
$("#foroGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { add: true, addtitle: 'Add Foro',
        edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit Foro',
        del: true, deltitle: 'Delete Foro',
        refresh: true, refreshtitle: 'Refresh data',
        search: true, searchtitle: 'Show Filters', 
        addfunc: addForo, editfunc: editForo, delfunc: deleteForo },
    {}, // default settings for edit
    {}, // default settings for add
    {}, // default settings for delete
    { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
    {}
);
```

and I have the requirement to add other functions like "CSV Export", "PDF Export", "Print", and so on...

It turns out that the space is going to be full and I would like to move the buttons in a toolbar on the top while still having the pager with navigator and record count info on the bottom.

Is it possible to achieve this configuration with jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663) old answer of mine. It seems to me, that it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I've extended the script [adding-buttons-in-jqgrid-toolbar](http://blog.anupamgupta.info/2010/01/adding-buttons-in-jqgrid-toolbar/) and added ability to add labels and anchors in same fashion.
Now you can use:

```
$("#tableID").toolbarButtonAdd("#t_tableID",{caption:"",position:"first",title:"Refresh", align:"right", buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh', onClickButton:function(){ $("#tableID").trigger("reloadGrid"); } })
$("#tableID").toolbarLabelAdd("#t_tableID", { caption: "0 Selected", position: "first", title: "", align: "right", id: 'lblSelectedRows' });
$("#tableID").toolbarAncherAdd("#t_tableID", { caption: "Select All", title: "Select All", id: 'btnSelectAll', onClickButton: function() { selectAllRecords(true); } });
```

Here is the library code:

```
$.fn.extend({
/*
*  
* The toolbar has the following properties
*   id of top toolbar: t_<tablename>
*   id of bottom toolbar: tb_<tablename>
*   class of toolbar: ui-userdata
* elem is the toolbar name to which button needs to be added. This can be 
*       #t_tablename - if button needs to be added to the top toolbar
*       #tb_tablename - if button needs to be added to the bottom toolbar
*/
toolbarButtonAdd: function(elem, p) {
    p = $.extend({
        caption: "newButton",
        title: '',
        buttonicon: 'ui-icon-newwin',
        onClickButton: null,
        position: "last"
    }, p || {});
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var tableString = "<table style='float:left;table-layout:auto;' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" class='ui-toolbar-table'>";
    tableString += "<tbody> <tr></tr></table>";
    //console.log("In toolbar button add method");
    /* 
    * Step 1: check whether a table is already added. If not add
    * Step 2: If there is no table already added then add a table
    * Step 3: Make the element ready for addition to the table 
    * Step 4: Check the position and corresponding add the element
    * Step 5: Add other properties 
    */
    //step 1 
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!this.grid) { return; }
        if (elem.indexOf("#") != 0) {
            elem = "#" + elem;
        }
        //step 2
        if ($(elem).children('table').length === 0) {
            $(elem).append(tableString);
        }
        //step 3
        var tbd = $("<td style=\"padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px\"></td>");
        $(tbd).addClass('ui-toolbar-button ui-corner-all').append("<div class='ui-toolbar-div'><span class='ui-icon " + p.buttonicon + "'></span>" + "<span>" + p.caption + "</span>" + "</div>").attr("title", p.title || "")
        .click(function(e) {
            if ($.isFunction(p.onClickButton)) { p.onClickButton(); }
            return false;
        })
        .hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover"); },
            function() { $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); }
        );
        if (p.id) { $(tbd).attr("id", p.id); }
        if (p.align) { $(elem).attr("align", p.align); }
        var findnav = $(elem).children('table');
        if (p.position === 'first') {
            if ($(findnav).find('td').length === 0) {
                $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
            } else {
                $("tr td:eq(0)", findnav).before(tbd);
            }
        } else {
            //console.log("not first");
            $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
        }
    });
},
toolbarLabelAdd: function(elem, p) {
    p = $.extend({
        caption: "newLabel",
        title: '',
        id: '',
        position: "last"
    }, p || {});
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var tableString = "<table style='float:left;table-layout:auto;' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" class='ui-toolbar-table'>";
    tableString += "<tbody> <tr></tr></table>";
    /* 
    * Step 1: check whether a table is already added. If not add
    * Step 2: If there is no table already added then add a table
    * Step 3: Make the element ready for addition to the table 
    * Step 4: Check the position and corresponding add the element
    * Step 5: Add other properties 
    */
    //step 1 
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!this.grid) { return; }
        if (elem.indexOf("#") != 0) {
            elem = "#" + elem;
        }
        //step 2
        if ($(elem).children('table').length === 0) {
            $(elem).append(tableString);
        }
        //step 3
        var tbd = $("<td style=\"padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px\"></td>");
        $(tbd).addClass('ui-corner-all').append("<div class='ui-toolbar-lbl'><span>" + p.caption + "</span>" + "</div>").attr("title", p.title || "");
        if (p.id) { $(tbd).attr("id", p.id); }
        if (p.align) { $(elem).attr("align", p.align); }
        var findnav = $(elem).children('table');
        if (p.position === 'first') {
            if ($(findnav).find('td').length === 0) {
                $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
            } else {
                $("tr td:eq(0)", findnav).before(tbd);
            }
        } else {
            $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
        }
    });
},
toolbarAncherAdd: function(elem, p) {
    p = $.extend({
        caption: "newButton",
        title: '',
        id: '',
        buttonicon: '',
        buttonclass : '',
        onClickButton: null,
        position: "last"
    }, p || {});
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var tableString = "<table style='float:left;table-layout:auto;' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" class='ui-toolbar-table'>";
    tableString += "<tbody> <tr></tr></table>";
    /* 
    * Step 1: check whether a table is already added. If not add
    * Step 2: If there is no table already added then add a table
    * Step 3: Make the element ready for addition to the table 
    * Step 4: Check the position and corresponding add the element
    * Step 5: Add other properties 
    */
    //step 1 
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!this.grid) { return; }
        if (elem.indexOf("#") != 0) {
            elem = "#" + elem;
        }
        //step 2
        if ($(elem).children('table').length === 0) {
            $(elem).append(tableString);
        }
        //step 3
        var tbd = $("<td style=\"padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px\"></td>"),
            iconClass = p.buttonicon.length === 0 ? "" : "<span class='ui-icon " + p.buttonicon + "'></span>"; 
        $(tbd).addClass('ui-toolbar-button ui-corner-all').append("<a class='ui-toolbar-a " + p.buttonClass + "'>" + iconClass + "<span>" + p.caption + "</span>" + "</a>").attr("title", p.title || "")
        .click(function(e) {
            if ($.isFunction(p.onClickButton)) { p.onClickButton(); }
            return false;
        });
        if (p.id) { $(tbd).attr("id", p.id); }
        if (p.align) { $(elem).attr("align", p.align); }
        var findnav = $(elem).children('table');
        if (p.position === 'first') {
            if ($(findnav).find('td').length === 0) {
                $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
            } else {
                $("tr td:eq(0)", findnav).before(tbd);
            }
        } else {
            //console.log("not first");
            $("tr", findnav).append(tbd);
        }
    });
},
});
```

Comment: How can we add separator ? using toolbarButtonAdd method ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add buttons to the top toolbar you have to do something like [this](http://blog.anupamgupta.info/2010/01/adding-buttons-in-jqgrid-toolbar/):

> Like I said in my previous article
>   adding buttons to jQGrid toolbar is a
>   bit tricky. You need to add the
>   following code in the end of the
>   jQGrid setup

After you have done that, you can use:

```
$("#tableID").toolbarButtonAdd("#t_tableID",{caption:"",position:"first",title:"Refresh", align:"right", buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh', onClickButton:function(){ $("#tableID").trigger("reloadGrid"); } });
```