# jqGrid inline edit: how to save again if post returns error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jQgrid row is edited using inline editing mode.
Pressing Enter sends data to server using http POST .
POST method returns status 400 Bad reguest if there was some error. errorofunc in code below show error in this 
case.
User corrects data in row and presses enter again.

Pressing enter is ignored, nothing happens. It looks like Enter key is unbound if 404 error is returned.
Changes in edited row are lost, they cannot saved.

I tried to set in errorfunc

restoreAfterError = false;
grid.restoreAfterErorr = false;

but row still cannot saved again after error.

How to allow to save correct row data after 400 error is returned ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastSelectedRow;
$(function () {
            var grid = $("#grid");
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: '/Grid/GetData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'POST',
                scroll: 1,
                multiselect: true,
                multiboxonly: true,
                scrollingRows : true,
                autoencode: true,
                colModel: [
        { name: 'Source', fixed: true, editable: true, width: 30 },
        { name: 'Est', fixed: true, editable: true, width: 271 },
        { name: 'Istopic', fixed: true, editable: true, width: 57 },
        {name: 'Critical', fixed: true, editable: true, width: 50}
    ],

                gridview: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'est',
                viewrecords: true,
                rowNum: 30,
                sortorder: "asc",
                editurl: '/Grid/Edit'
            });

            $("#grid").jqGrid('bindKeys', {
                onEnter: function(rowid) {
                    doeditRow(rowid);
                }
            }  );

        });

        function doeditRow(rowID) {
            var grid2 = $("#grid");
            if (rowID && rowID !== lastSelectedRow) {
                grid2.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelectedRow);
                lastSelectedRow = rowID;
            }
            invokeEditRow();
        }

        function errorfunc(rowID, response) {
            // todo: why this does not allow Enter key to continue ase after error:
            restoreAfterError = false;
            $("#grid").restoreAfterErorr = false;
            alert(response.responseText);
            lastSelectedRow = rowID;
            invokeEditRow();
            return true;
        }


        function invokeEditRow() {
             $("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', lastSelectedRow ,true,null, null, null, {},
                 null,
                 errorfunc
             );
        }
    </script>

<div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%;">
    <table id="grid">
    </table>
    <div id="pager">
    </div>
</div>
```

> UPDATE: errrofunc calls editrow which
>   according to
>   https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js
>   should set enter key again to save.
>   For unknown reason this does not
>   occur.

UPDATE: in errorfunc grid. is changed to

```
        $("#grid").restoreAfterErorr = false;
```

according to Oleg comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variable `grid` inside of `errorfunc` implementation (`grid.restoreAfterErorr`). The `grid` 
is `undefined` and you have exception in the line.

**UPDATED**: ou should replace `alert(response.responseText);` to

```
$.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap,'<div class="ui-state-error">'+
    response.responseText +'</div>', $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'right'});
```

to see the same styled dialog box as in the standard case. The `errorfunc` from the inline editing is responsible to display the error message itself.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you. I updated testcase by changing `grid` to `$("#grid")`. Problem persists. To test this you can use the same private test url which I sent to you.  Enter more than 30 characters to first (Allikas) column and press enter. Error message appears. Edit Allikas columns to have less that 30 characters and press Enter again. This enter press is ignored, data is not saved. How to save data after error ? Btw. For unknow reason even if grid. is used, exception does not occur in grid. line. Proper alert box with error from database still appears.

Comment: @Andrus: Could you replace `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`?

Comment: @Andrus: It seems I start to understand what wrong is in your site. You enter in the editing mode too frequently. For example inside of `errorfunc` you should not call `invokeEditRow`. Moreover it seems that if you press enter to save the row contain you not only save it, but additionally receive the `keypress` event to start inline editing (see `bindKeys`) which follows to very stranger behavior.

Comment: @Andrus: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg: I added all changes you required to the test url.
Problem persists. I removed editRow call from errorfunc. After that row cannot edited after error at all.
I tried to change errorfunc error message to modeless like in loaderror but this message does not appear.

Comment: @Andrus: The code of `errorMessage` has too many errors and you produce exception. For example in the statement `$('#' + $("#grid").id + '_err').remove();` you should replace `$("#grid").id` to `$("#grid")[0].id`. In the next statement you use `grid.closest`, but you don't define `var grid=$("#grid");` before. So exception will be thrown. In the same statement you has much more errors where you try to use `$("#grid").id` and `$("#grid").style` instead of `$("#grid")[0].id` and `$("#grid")[0].style`. Probably the real problem will come later, but one have to fix the code of errorMessage before.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you very much. I fixed errorMessage procedure in testcase. Now it shows error message properly. I dont understand when `$("#grid")[0]` and when `$("#grid")` should be used.

Comment: @Andrus: It's very easy. There are DOM element which correspond `<table id="grid">` element. The jQuery object `$("#grid")` is the wrapper over the element. If no element with `$("#grid")` exist you can verify this using `$("#grid").length`. If selector used in `$("#grid")` do find DOM elements you can access the elements with respect of indexer: `$("#grid")[i]`. Because id selector '#' get back always one elements (if you don't have double ids bug on your page) you will always get with `$("#grid")[0]` the DOM element which has `id` `style` and other properties.

Comment: @Andrus: if you need use **jQuery methods** like `closest`, `parent`. `text`, `attr`. `bind` and so on you should use jQuery object: `$("#grid")`. So you should just know which methods and properties has jQuery wrapper object and which methods and properties (from W3 specification) has DOM element.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you very much for clear explanation. No we have modeless non-offensive error message if error occurs on save.