# jqGrid error message from server side exception

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I've added the following code for my jqgrid:

```
changeTextFormat = function (data) {

                return "Activity or one from the same price group already used";
            };
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {errorTextFormat: changeTextFormat })
```

It works great for insert and I get the error message appearing in the top of the dialog.

However for edits it's not working so well. Instead a massive dialog is appearing with the error message.

I'm currently thinking that it's because I'm using inline editing so it has to pop up a whole new dialog. Is there a way to format this dialog better. I'm pretty sure that for the inline edits it's not even running through `changeTextFormat` after an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. By changing of `jQuery.jgrid.edit` you set [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) only for the form editing. In case of the usage inline editing you have to use `errorfunc` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow).

You can easy see the difference between [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) and `errorfunc` parameter. If in the `errorTextFormat` you should return the error message which will be used in the error message, the callback function `errorfunc` should *display* the corresponding error message itself. If you want to have the same look of the error dialog you can use `$.jgrid.info_dialog` method. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217630/jqgrid-inline-edit-how-to-save-again-if-post-returns-error/6218257#6218257) you could find the corresponding code fragment. See additionally [the code fragment](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L268-L273) of the jqGrid source code.