# How do I get a navigator on both the top and bottom of a jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, navigator

I'd like to have a navigator on both the top and bottom of the jqGrid. I have tried using the cloneToTop property on the grid and on the pager. It clones the elements but does not apply the correct styles (inspecting with FireBug reveals missing ui- styles). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the parameter `cloneToTop` is the correct way. Look at [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientSidePagingToolbar.htm) which is example from the answer on [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663). It do of case not exactly what you ask, but it shows how `cloneToTop`  work and how one can modify some results produced by `cloneToTop`.

Which styles you miss on the elements (which element?) of the top navigator, which you can see on the bottom navigator?

In general `cloneToTop` use very easy jqGrid functions. You can use jQuery.appendTo to move any element from one navigation bar to another one. In other [my answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-controls-in-the-navbar-for-jqgrid/) you can find an example of such movement (of case not exactly for you case, but all work in the same way).