# Only two pager div in a jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need a jqGrid like the below image.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/jqgrid.jpg/

How can I get that type of jqGrid??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `cloneToTop:true` parameter of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402455/unable-to-position-pager-navigation-bar-above-jqgrid/4402903#4402903) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663) for more details.

Comment: "@Oleg" I tried as your way and got a output like below

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/jqgrid.jpg/ 

I would like to remove the red marked portion that is named list table(may be).

Thanks for reply

Comment: @Foysal: If you need you can hide the column headers with the code like `grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid-view').find('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').hide();` where `grid` is the `table` element of your jqGrid  (`var grid = $('#list')`).