# Adding Jqgrid navButtonAdd icon to the top(cloned) navigator

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using navButtonAdd to have a column chooser in my jqgrid but it adds the button to the bottom navigation bar. Is it possible to add the same icon to the top of my cloned navigation bar. Here is my code...

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
         ......
         toppager: true,
         ....
    );  

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {cloneToTop: true, edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false},
        { }, { }, { }, { } );

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
    caption : "",
    buttonicon : "ui-icon-calculator",
    title : "Choose Columns",
    onClickButton : function() {
        jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('columnChooser');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the toppager will be created it will have the id constructed from the grid id and "_toppager", so it will be "grid_toppager" in your case. So you should use

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {...});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402903/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557663/315935) for more details and for demos.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I was able to fix it using same approach.                                                          var msgGrid = jQuery("#messagesGrid");
msgGrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + msgGrid[0].id + '_toppager_left', {
 
 });

Comment: @varaprakash: You are welcome! It's what I mean. By the way, if the `id` of the grid could have some special characters (which is not recommended) you should use `'#' + $.jgrid.jqID(msgGrid[0].id) + '_toppager_left'` instead (see about escaping or meta-characters [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).

Answer (score 0):

For basic functionality, setting the toppager: true and cloneToTop: true would suffice as below.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    pager: '#pager',toppager: true  
});

$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{
    cloneToTop:true
});
```