# Unable to position pager (navigation bar) above jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, position, pager

According the the jqGrid documentation, I should be able to place the pager above or below the jqGrid by moving the pager div. Unfortunately, the pager always renders below the grid.

```
<div id="pager"></div>
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jqGrid configuration (related to the pager) looks like:

```
pager: '#pager',
pginput: false,
pgbuttons: false,
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should use `toppager:true` jqGrid option instead. You don't need define `<div id="pager"></div>` and use `pager: '#pager'` parameter. The id of the pager from the top of jqGrid will be "list_toppager" (id of the table element appended with "_toppager").

If you want to add navigator you can use

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#list_toppager');
```

If you use define `<div id="pager"></div>` and use `pager: '#pager'` parameter you will have **two**  pager: one with `id="list_toppager"` on top of the grid and anothe with `id="pager"` on the bottom. If you want use both top and bottom pager you can use

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{cloneToTop:true});
```

and then move or remove (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663) for more details and the demo example). You can also very easy move buttons from one toolbar to the other using [jQuery.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678904/adding-button-to-jqgrid-top-toolbar/2679672#2679672)).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Oleg. Excellent as usual.

Comment: Oleg + StackOverflow = The real jqGrid documentation

Answer (score 0):

use a $ append. the html above table is like this

```
<div id="export"></div>
```

add the id and use a promise().done(): "exportButton"

```
$(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', self.options.pagerSelector, { id: "exportButton", caption: "Export to CSV", buttonicon: "ui-icon-newwin", onClickButton: function() { self._exportToCSV(self, grid); }, position: "last", title: "Export to CSV", cursor: "pointer" })
.promise().done(function() {
    //reposition export button
    $("#export").append($("#exportButton"));
    $("#exportButton").addClass("pull-right").show();
});
```