# In jqgrid, can I put the pager on the top left

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pager

when using jqgrid, I see i can add the pager to the top by doing this:

```
    toppager: true,
```

which works great,  but i wanted to see if i can align this to the left of that row instead of putting it in the center.  Is this possible ?

Comment: which exactly components of [the pager](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/lib/exe/detail.php?id=wiki%3Apager&media=wiki:pager.png) you will have in the toppager on the left?

Comment: @Oleg - the whole section that is in the middle now that shows Page X of Y and also shows the dropdown of number of items per page.

Comment: Do you want to set two pager: one at the bottom and another on the top or only one pager on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place the pager element left top which is per default at the top center you should just hide the div which is on the top left position.

```
$('#' + grid[0].id + '_toppager_left').hide();
```

where `var grid = $('#list')` for example. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithPoppagerLeft.htm):

[image]

Another old answer describes how you can move different pager elements between the top and the bottom pager. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402455/unable-to-position-pager-navigation-bar-above-jqgrid/4402903#4402903) gives some more general information about the pagers.