# jqGrid - how to hide bottom page and show top pager only?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm currently using `toppager: true` to show the pager at the top. The bottom pager shows up naturally as the default. How do I keep the top pager visible while hiding the bottom pager instead?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just don't use any `pager` option of jqGrid. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402903/315935) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

To enable display of only toppager in jqGrid, do not use pager property and use only toppager property.

See [here](http://www.prowebguru.com/2015/01/jqgrid-show-top-pager-bottom-pager/) for other possible combinations of jqgrid to show hide top or bottom pager.