# How to make jqGrid have two different pagers?

Tags: jqgrid

I can get two pagers in jqGrid, one is on top, and one is on the bottom.
But I want to make the top pager show recordText on left, and the bottom pager show navigator buttons on the left.
The reason I want this is my grid is too wide, I don't want to use scrollbar to get the recordText or navigator buttons.

Answer (score 0):

here this will help you...you can have two pagers one at top and one at bottom and based on your requirements you can hide a few things from pager.

[Unable to position pager (navigation bar) above jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402455/unable-to-position-pager-navigation-bar-above-jqgrid)