# jqgrid inlineNav cloneToTop?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am playing with jqGrid and I have a combination of both a pager (with View and Refresh) and an inlineNav (with Add, Edit, Save, Cancel).

I have toppager:true and cloneToTop:true which places the pager controls, both at top and bottom. However I can't seem to do the same with my inlineNav.

Full code follows, but I tried to do the following, but the top buttons do not respond properly and it's a bit of a mess:

```
$("#pager_left").clone().appendTo("#list_toppager_left");
```

Can anyone help?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var lastSel;

  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'db.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:[
    /*...*/
    ],
    colModel :[ 
      /*...*/
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    autowidth:true,
    height: "100%",
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[20,50,100,1000],
    loadtext: 'Loading...',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname:'BUSINESS',
    sortorder:"ASC",
    multiselect:false,
    sortable:true,
    toppager:true,
    ignorecase:true,
    gridview: true,
    editurl:"db_edit.php",
    caption: 'Bath BID',
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
            $('#list').saveRow(lastSel);
            lastSel=id; 
        }
        }
  }).navGrid('#pager', {
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:true,
    view:true,
    search:false,
    viewtext:"View", 
    closeOnEscape:true,
    edittext:"Edit", 
    refreshtext:"Refresh", 
    addtext:"Add", 
    deltext:"Delete", 
    searchtext:"Search",
    cloneToTop:true},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});

    $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
    $("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager', { 
        edittext:"Edit", 
        addtext:"Add",
        savetext:"Save",
        canceltext:"Cancel",
        cloneToTop:true
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analysed your problem. First of all the option `cloneToTop: true` is supported by [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters), but not by [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav). Moreover the ids of the buttons of will be constructed using the grid id as the prefix. As the result one will have

```
list_iladd, list_iledit, list_ilsave, list_ilcancel
```

as ids. On the other side the ids of the standard navGrid buttons from will have the following ids after `cloneToTop: true`:

```
view_list, del_list,
view_list_top, del_list_top
```

So one can't just call `navGrid` twice with both pager:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#list_toppager', {
    edittext: "Edit",
    addtext: "Add",
    savetext: "Save",
    canceltext: "Cancel"
});
$("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
    edittext: "Edit",
    addtext: "Add",
    savetext: "Save",
    canceltext: "Cancel"
});
```

One will receive as the results **id duplicates** (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-cloneToTop.htm)).

Making manual id modifications before calling the `inlineNav` at the second time will also not really help (see [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-cloneToTop1.htm)) because the code which will be executed after clicking on the inline buttons use the same rules of id building. So only the buttons having original ids will be disabled or enabled.

I can summarize: the current implementation of `inlineNav` don't support the top pager. I would recommend you use `inlineNav` only once. If you need to have the icons in the second pager you should better examine the source code of `inlineNav` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L424) for example) and add in the same way new buttons with respect of `navButtonAdd` and using another ids.

I hope that in the next version the code of `inlineNav` will be extended to support two pager at the same time.

**UPDATED**: I forgot to mention, that I fixed a little position of the text relative to icons in the navigator bars. It is not the main subject of your question, but probably it will be interesting for you too:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div span.ui-icon {
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div span.ui-icon {
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit clunky, but for a quick win I just duplicated the code within grid.inlinedit.js in order to recreate buttons that do the same thing in both top and bottom bars... it seems to work.

```
            if(o.add) {
            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', elem,{
                caption : o.addtext,
                title : o.addtitle,
                buttonicon : o.addicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_iladd",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    $($t).jqGrid('addRow', o.addParams);
                    if(!o.addParams.useFormatter) {
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    }
                }
            });

            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + $($t)[0].id + '_toppager_left',{
                caption : o.addtext,
                title : o.addtitle,
                buttonicon : o.addicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_top_iladd",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    $($t).jqGrid('addRow', o.addParams);
                    if(!o.addParams.useFormatter) {
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        if(o.edit) {
            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', elem,{
                caption : o.edittext,
                title : o.edittitle,
                buttonicon : o.editicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_iledit",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        $($t).jqGrid('editRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });

            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + $($t)[0].id + '_toppager_left',{
                caption : o.edittext,
                title : o.edittitle,
                buttonicon : o.editicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_top_iledit",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        $($t).jqGrid('editRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });


        }
        if(o.save) {
            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', elem,{
                caption : o.savetext || '',
                title : o.savetitle || 'Save row',
                buttonicon : o.saveicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_ilsave",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        if($("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(sr), "#"+$.jgrid.jqID($t.p.id) ).hasClass("jqgrid-new-row")) {
                            var opers = $t.p.prmNames,
                            oper = opers.oper;
                            if(!o.editParams.extraparam) {
                                o.editParams.extraparam = {};
                            }
                            o.editParams.extraparam[oper] = opers.addoper;
                        }
                        $($t).jqGrid('saveRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');

            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + $($t)[0].id + '_toppager_left',{
                caption : o.savetext || '',
                title : o.savetitle || 'Save row',
                buttonicon : o.saveicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_top_ilsave",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        if($("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(sr), "#"+$.jgrid.jqID($t.p.id) ).hasClass("jqgrid-new-row")) {
                            var opers = $t.p.prmNames,
                            oper = opers.oper;
                            if(!o.editParams.extraparam) {
                                o.editParams.extraparam = {};
                            }
                            o.editParams.extraparam[oper] = opers.addoper;
                        }
                        $($t).jqGrid('saveRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
        if(o.cancel) {
            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', elem,{
                caption : o.canceltext || '',
                title : o.canceltitle || 'Cancel row editing',
                buttonicon : o.cancelicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_ilcancel",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        $($t).jqGrid('restoreRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');

            $($t).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + $($t)[0].id + '_toppager_left',{
                caption : o.canceltext || '',
                title : o.canceltitle || 'Cancel row editing',
                buttonicon : o.cancelicon,
                id : $t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel",
                onClickButton : function ( e ) {
                    var sr = $($t).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                    if(sr) {
                        $($t).jqGrid('restoreRow', sr, o.editParams);
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();                         
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#"+$t.p.id+"_top_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
```

Comment: It's about the same which I suggested in my answer. I think only that one should not add always the buttons in `'#' + $($t)[0].id + '_toppager_left'`. There are already parameter `elem`. I would add buttons only in the `elem` pager, but I would use ids constructed from the `id` of the `elem`. Moreover I would use additional classes to `iladd`, `iledit` and so on buttons then the code for disabling or enabling of the buttons can be shorter. I would also to use a little another rules how to construct the ids of the buttons to have no possible conflicts with buttons added by `inlineNav`.

Comment: Please post additionally a short comment to my answer if you update the text of your question of if you post one more answer. Only in the case I would have notification about this.