# How do I customize the Add button in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, usability

I have a jqGrid and when I do a seach I get a small dialog. There is a Add button at the top which has a "+" sign to add rows for advanced searching. Is it possible to change this button text to a plain old school "Add" without hacking into js library. Is there any way by writing an extendion? Is so how?

```
<input type="button" value="+" title="Add rule" class="add-rule ui-add">
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters) has some parameters which can be used to change the look of navigator buttons. I used additionally `toppager: true` option of jqGrid and `cloneToTop: true` option of `navGrid` for the case that one uses top pager. If one just create the navigator buttons with respect of the call

```js
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    cloneToTop: true,
    view: true,
    add: true,
    edit: true,
    addtext: 'Add',
    edittext: 'Edit',
    deltext: 'Delete',
    searchtext: 'Search',
    refreshtext: 'Reload',
    viewtext: 'View'
});
```

one will see the results like

[image]

I used `rowNum: 2` for the tests only to reduce the height of the pictures.

If I correct understand you, you want to have pure text buttons. To remove the icons from the buttons one can execute the following additional lines

```js
var pagerId = 'pager', gridId = $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id);
$('#' + pagerId).find('.navtable span.ui-icon').remove();
$('#' + gridId + '_toppager').find('.navtable span.ui-icon').remove();
```

The `gridId` will be set to `'list'`. One need to use `$.jgrid.jqID` if the grid id could contain [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). The results will be

[image]

Next step will be to fix right and left the padding or margin of the buttons to show the texts better:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .navtable .ui-pg-div,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .navtable .ui-pg-div {
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

The results will be improved to the following

[image]

Now we need fix the position of the pager. We can do this with respect of

```js
$('#' + pagerId + '_left').width($('#' + pagerId + ' .navtable').width());
$('#' + gridId + '_toppager_left').width($('#' + gridId + '_toppager .navtable').width());
$('#' + pagerId + '_center')[0].style.width='';
$('#' + gridId + '_toppager_center')[0].style.width='';
```

and have the following results

[image]

or remove additionally unused right part of the pager with

```js
$('#' + pagerId + '_right').remove();
$('#' + gridId + '_toppager_right').remove();
```

which places the pager in the middle of the rest place on the pager:

[image]

In my opinion it's mostly the matter of taste which look is better. You can see the resulting demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavButtonsWithText0.htm).

Alternatively you can do use icons *over* the text, but place the text *under* the icons. You can see 
details in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavButtonsWithText1.htm) which produces the following results:

[image]

**UPDATED**: To customize the "Add rule" or "Add group" buttons you can use [afterRedraw](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) option:

```js
afterRedraw: function () {
    $('input.add-rule',this).val('Add new rule');
    $('input.add-group',this).val('Add new rule group');
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomizeAddRuleButtonOfAdvancedSearching.htm) which use the option produce the searching dialog like the following:

[image]

(the button "Add group" exist if `multipleGroup: true` are used and the "Add rule" button exist if `multipleSearch: true` are used).

**UPDATED 2**: One can improve the visibility of the searching dialog if one would use jQuery UI Buttons:

```js
afterRedraw: function () {
    $('input.add-rule',this).val('Add new rule').button();
    $('input.add-group',this).val('Add new group or rules').button();
    $('input.delete-rule',this).val('Delete rule').button();
    $('input.delete-group',this).val('Delete group').button();
}
```

The result dialog can be like the following

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was when a user click on the search button as shown in the figure, it brings a pop up box. The Add button for the search criteria is a + sign. I want to change this. How do I do this? Your answer doesn't explain this....

Comment: @chugh97: You should formulate your question more clear. The title of the question say nothing about Searching dialog. The "+" Button is the "Add" new row button. Your original question isn't complex. You can use [afterRedraw](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) option in the form `afterRedraw: function () {$('input.add-rule',this).val('Add new rule');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I am sorry my question was not very well understood in first instance. I'll try next time....