# how to localize button tooltips in jqgrid advanced search dialog

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

It seems like tooltips `Add subgroup`, `Add rule`, `Delete rule` are hard coded in jqgrid code.

```
            inputAddSubgroup = $("<input type='button' value='+ {}' title='Add subgroup' class='add-group'/>");
```

How to localize them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted to trirand my detailed [suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/some-problems-in-grid-filter-js-module/#p25672) and reminded Tony twice about the problem later.

Additionally I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854864/315935) a workaround which allows to customize the Advanced searching dialog

[image]

Simple modification of the original demo make the following [new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomizeAddRuleButtonOfAdvancedSearching1.htm)

[image]

I used the following code

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    overlay: 0,
    afterRedraw: function () {
        $('input.add-rule',this).button().val('Add new rule')
            .attr('title', 'My Add new rule tooltip');
        $('input.add-group',this).button().val('Add new group or rules')
            .attr('title', 'My new group or rules tooltip');
        $('input.delete-rule',this).button().val('Delete rule')
            .attr('title', 'My Delete rule tooltip');
        $('input.delete-group',this).button().val('Delete group')
            .attr('title', 'My Delete group tooltip');
        $(this).find("table.group:not(:first)").css({
            borderWidth: "1px",
            borderStyle: "dashed"
        });
    }
});
```

I added additional border in groups because I find there helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. If search dialog contains may rows, bottom rows and search buttons are not visible. How to force vertical scrollbar to appear in this case ? In my application borders are not drawn around input and select emements in advanced search dialog. I dont see any border disabling in css file. What may cause this and aow to enable borders?

Comment: if many rows are added in search dialog, vertical scrollbar appears automatically. However if advanced search dialog is opened, scrollbar does not appear, bottom rules and buttons are not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery again, for example: `$('select the button').attr('title', 'New localized title')`