# jqGrid using your own delete style button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Am new to `jqGrid` for about 2 hours now,

I had added deleting from a row successfully. so i.e.

```
colModel: [

 .....

name: 'actions', index: 'actions', width: 105, editable:false, formatter: 'actions',
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    editbutton: false,
    delOptions: { url: getURL('Action') + 'method?f='+$('#id').val()}
   }

],
```

This shows a general trash can, but I wondering if its possible to show your own button?

This http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons looks quite promising,

But I do not think it would work with the code I have pasted above and I don't really want to change it as the functionality from JS to C# is working OK.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307628/replace-delete-icon-of-jqgrid-with-custom-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the formatter "actions" do is nothing special. It places just an icon in the column and calls the method [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) if the button clicked. `formatoptions.delOptions` value will be just used as th eoption of `delGridRow`. The icon is nothing more as `<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>`. So you can place any other icon in the column using [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). The custom formatter is just a callback function which will be called during constructing the cell content (the content of `<td>`). The returned value have to be **string** which contains HTML fragment. jqGrid will just place the content in the grid column.

So if you would create the column with your custom icon you will do the half of the job. To call `delGridRow` with the options which you need you can use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` callback. jqGrid register *common* (one) event handler for the whole grid and the event handler will be called because of the event bubbling. So the `e` parameter of `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` is the Event object from the `click` event which were fired. The property `e.target` is the cell or some subelement which was clicked. It hold all the information which you could require.

I hope that you can created the solution yourself based on the above information and demos from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) (with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon13.htm)), [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShKDX/82/) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19444877/315935) and some other.